# Why are monocots more advanced than dicots. Shouldn't more complexity mean more evolved?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy

Features like pith, endodermis, pericycle, medullary rays and secondary growth are not present in monocots. How are monocots still more advanced?

Comment: ”more advanced” seems subjective, here. Can you link a source for that claim or provide more explanation?

Comment: After seeing hutchinsons classification this question seems wrong , the categories of monocot and dicot are not correct to group 'types of angiosperms' and to conclude that one of the groups is more evolved or primitive . Sometimes it's the plants of monocot which happen to be more developed while it's dicots in some cases .

Comment: short answer no advanced is subjective, to a beetle having an exoskeleton might seem more "advanced"

Comment: Yeah , for a land animal  it is strength which helps it in fight  situation .while for a bird which has less land animal enemies due to its flight , having strength is not useful for some birds and hence some  are small making flight easier and have bright colours to attract mates . These two traits can't be compared since they are developed depending upon the different environment they live in